# How do I automatically close an eclipse view?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

I have used Eclipse IDE for as long as I have been programming, a few years, and I think I remember a feature for the Console view that would automatically close it when the program finished running. I am trying to find the same functionality now. So my questions are: Is the automatic Console close a feature, and if it is, how do I use it.

Eclipse Neon 4.5 (or 4.6) Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

The closest feature that I know of is a Preferences option to "Remove terminated launches when a new launch is created" which can be found in **Preferences** > **Run/Debug** > **Launching**.

On the Console view toolbar, there are also convenient `X` buttons to easily remove the current or all terminated launch consoles.

Comment: I guess my question is just lazy. I don't want to keep clicking on the console window whenever I'm fiddling with values. Thanks anyway!